# Rails Capybara link_to test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara

I am testing a link with Capybara.

My HAML view template (link on last line):

```
%section.black_background.white_foreground
  .container
    .pricing-blurb
      %p This means unlimited Companies, Projects and Clients, + ongoing customer support.
      = link_to 'Get Started', new_signup_path, class: 'signup-button'
```

My best attempt at the test:

```
  it 'has the correct links in the page' do
    within '.pricing-blurb' do
      expect(find_link('Get Started')[:href]).to eql(new_signup_path)
    end  
  end
```

I know its wrong because my code isn't a :href

Comment: What error do  you get when you run the test you mentioned?

Comment: @joshua.paling It passes. http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FFinders%3Afind_link i feel like its because it doesn't know what :href is so it just passes it. It says its optional. Im trying to write the test without the :href.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to test the href you can just do

```
expect(page).to have_link('Get Started')
```

If you do want to verify the href too you can do

```
expect(page).to have_link('Get Started', href: new_signup_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code suffices. link_to`is a helper which generates the following HTML:`anything

Im new to capybara but our Lead Programmer said its spot on.

```
it 'has the correct links in the page' do
    within '.pricing-blurb' do
      expect(find_link('Get Started')[:href]).to eql(new_signup_path)
    end  
  end
```

**Is correct**

Comment: This is only correct if you're sure the link is not dynamically changing.  You're better off using the have_link matcher from my answer since it reads better and will use Capybara's waiting behavior in the case the link is being dynamically modified